# Running an old project of mine, but on a newer matlab version. Errors popping up with table() method. Did something change?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

This is the lbp function of a facial expression recognition project that I'd created. The matlab version that this was created in as 2013. I am currently running this on 2017a.

Here is the function that I'm trying to run:

```
% result = lbp(I) returns the LBP histogram of the image I

function result = lbp(image) 

d_image=double(image);
radius=1;
neighbours=8;
neighbour_points=zeros(neighbours,2);

% Angle step.
a = 2*pi/neighbours;

for i = 1:neighbours
    neighbour_points(i,1) = -radius*sin((i-1)*a);

    neighbour_points(i,2) = radius*cos((i-1)*a);

end

% Determine the dimensions of the input image.
[m1,n1]=size(image);



miny=min(neighbour_points(:,1));

maxy=max(neighbour_points(:,1));

minx=min(neighbour_points(:,2));

maxx=max(neighbour_points(:,2));


blocksizey=ceil(max(maxy,0))-floor(min(miny,0))+1;

blocksizex=ceil(max(maxx,0))-floor(min(minx,0))+1;



% Coordinates of origin (0,0) in the block
origy=1-floor(min(miny,0));

origx=1-floor(min(minx,0));

% Minimum allowed size for the input image depends
% on the radius of the used LBP operator.
if(n1 < blocksizex || m1 < blocksizey)
    error('Small input image. Must be at least (2*radius+1) x (2*radius+1)');
end

% Calculate dx and dy;
dx = n1 - blocksizex;
dy = m1 - blocksizey;

% Fill the center pixel matrix C.
C = image(origy:origy+dy,origx:origx+dx);
%disp(C);    
d_C = double(C);
% Initialize the result matrix with zeros.
result=zeros(dy+1,dx+1);

%Computing the LBP code image

for i = 1:neighbours
    y = neighbour_points(i,1)+origy;

    x = neighbour_points(i,2)+origx;

    % Calculate floors, ceils and rounds for the x and y.
    fy = floor(y); cy = ceil(y); ry = round(y);
    fx = floor(x); cx = ceil(x); rx = round(x);
    % Check if interpolation is needed.
    if (abs(x - rx) < 1e-6) && (abs(y - ry) < 1e-6)
        % Interpolation is not needed, use original datatypes
        N = image(ry:ry+dy,rx:rx+dx);
        D = N >= C;
    else
        % Interpolation needed, use double type images
        ty = y - fy;
        tx = x - fx;        
        % Calculate the interpolation weights.
        w1 = roundn((1 - tx) * (1 - ty),-6);
        w2 = roundn(tx * (1 - ty),-6);
        w3 = roundn((1 - tx) * ty,-6);
        % w4 = roundn(tx * ty,-6) ;
        w4 = roundn(1 - w1 - w2 - w3, -6);        
        % Compute interpolated pixel values
        N = w1*d_image(fy:fy+dy,fx:fx+dx) + w2*d_image(fy:fy+dy,cx:cx+dx) + w3*d_image(cy:cy+dy,fx:fx+dx) + w4*d_image(cy:cy+dy,cx:cx+dx);
        N = roundn(N,-4);
        D = N >= d_C;
    end
    % Update the result matrix.
    v = 2^(i-1);
    result = result + v*D;
    if i==neighbours    

    end
end

load('binvector.mat');
bins = 59;
for i = 1:size(result,1)
    for j = 1:size(result,2)
        result(i,j)=table(result(i,j)+1);
    end
end


% calculating histogram
result=hist(result(:),0:(bins-1));




end

function x = roundn(x, n)
if n<0
    p=10 ^ -n;
    x=round(p*x)/p;
elseif n>0
    p=10^n;
    x=p*round(x/p);
else
    x=round(x);
end
end
```

And here is the error that popped up:

```
Error using tabular/double (line 148)
Undefined function 'double' for input arguments of type 'table'. To convert to numeric, use the TABLE2ARRAY function, or
extract data using dot or brace subscripting.

Error in lbp (line 104)
        result(i,j)=table(result(i,j)+1);
```

I havent touched matlab in a long while, and so not sure how to tackle this, or what a suitable replacement method would be. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Cris, thanks for replying. That was the first thing I tried, but did not work. Proceeded to give another sequence of errors. Also, I think table() here was used to convert doubles to a table structure, and the suggested method in the error does the opposite.

Comment: Looking at your code that throws the error, it seems to me that the `table` here is not meant to be the `table` method that creates a table object, but rather an array that is being indexed into. `table` looks like it's meant to be a look-up table. Likely an array stored in the `binvector.mat` file, which is being loaded a few lines earlier. Is it successfully loading this file? Maybe the file got overwritten by a different one, that does not have a `table` array?